# React / Redux - what if multiple shopping carts have to displayed once but you only have one flag inside the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was reading an article about problems of redux being a singleton and reacts components having many instances. The example was about a shopping cart, when you need to display two shopping carts on the screen simultaneously, with only having one isCartFull flag inside the store. The article was kinda about bad sides of redux without 'solutions' so I wonder:
What would be a good approach here? Having multiple flags doesnt seem right to me (what if its not just 2 shopping carts or things like that). Another solution I can think of is to take it out of redux and provide flags insight the component. 
Is there any other / better solution?
Thanks!!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. If you have two shopping carts with unrelated data then you need to objects in the store, each with its data--exactly like any other solution.

Comment: Can you link the article?  From the way you describe it, I'd still use Redux for this.

Comment: Yes Its not about not using redux, I m asking what would be the best choice for a case like that. The article: https://codeburst.io/the-ugly-side-of-redux-6591fde68200

Comment: @dave Newton - its not about data sharing etc, its more about whether or not the shopping cart is full and based on that do something, while the flag is for all carts isFull

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Redux doesn't seem to be relevant at all; where the data is stored doesn't really matter.